# How to make Views fill all LinearLayout size

Tags: android, xml, view, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to create some `Views` dynamically  in `LinearLayout`, the issue when the number of the created views is small the result looks like this :

[image]

And I want to make `Views` fill all `LinearLayout` like this :

[image]

**LinearLayout  XML:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/palette_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**View XML:**

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

**Java:**

```
 public class ColorPaletteResultsFragment extends Fragment {
    public ColorPaletteResultsFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_palette_results, container, false);
        configure(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void configure(View view) {
        LinearLayout palletContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.palette_container);
        fillPalletColors(mPalette, palletContainer);
    }

    private void fillPalletColors(List<Integer> colors, LinearLayout paletteContainer) {
        if (getActivity() != null && isAdded()) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
             for (int color : colors) {
                    View palletColor = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suggested_color_item, paletteContainer, false);
                    palletColor.setBackgroundColor(color);
                    paletteContainer.addView(palletColor);
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and it is working fine for me. Do you change the layout params anywhere? paletteContainer is a reference to palette_container? I think you may need to share more info/code

Comment: @W0rmH0le Massive thanks for ur help, I've updated my question with more code

Answer (score 0):

For each of the Views you created, it looks like you'll need to assign a weight to the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` params for that view.

The weight would be 1/n where n is the number of views.

```
int viewCount = 6;
View view = new View(getContext());
            float weight = 1/viewCount;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,weight);
            view.setLayoutParams(params);
```